# XMLHttpRequest misformats URL- Error 405

Tags: javascript, rest

I am sending XMLHttpRequest to Rest API server like this:

```
function sendPostRequest (accessToken)
{
  // construct an HTTP request
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


  //build data
  var data = {};
  data["accessToken"] = accessToken ;

  xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:61103/api/Test", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));

  xhttp.onloadend = function () {

  };
}
```

This is received by ASP.NET Web API:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(string userToken)
    {
            //stuff
    }
```

However, I always get back 405 error. Most likely because the request does not have Rest parameter (think no suitable overloading), ie looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:61103/api/testAPI HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:61103
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 21
Origin: http://localhost:61103
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:61103/Testlogin.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

{"accessToken":"asd"}
```

Notice, the data is not included in the link, but rather at the bottom.

In addition, this works

```
xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:61103/api/Test?userToken=XXXX", true);
```

Comment: Data in the body of the request is how POST request works.

Comment: Status code 405 means "Method Not Allowed". You probably shouldn't do a POST request but a GET request.

Comment: what type of server and backend language are you using?

Comment: Michael, I just added edit- ASP.NET C# web api with IHttpActionResult type.

Comment: cool, and using IIS Server?

Comment: So is it `/api/Test` or `/api/testAPI`?

Comment: @Phil, well spotted :) neither though- I edited this for pasting. The actual API link is more complicated and works fine.

Comment: What is `onloadend`?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#handler-xhr-onloadend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an optional parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(string userToken = "")
{
        // base code off of param
}
```

This is based off of ASP documentation here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection

> For example, consider the following action:
>
> public void Get(int id)
>
> The id parameter binds to the URI. Therefore, this action can only
>   match a URI that contains a value for "id", either in the route
>   dictionary or in the query string.
>
> Optional parameters are an exception, because they are optional. For
>   an optional parameter, it's OK if the binding can't get the value from
>   the URI.

So I would think you either need edit the ajax url for no value, or use optional params in your server code.

If its not that it could be your IIS config, see here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

Comment: I'm not sure if your actual code was written this way I was just basing my answer off of what you posted

Comment: I get 404 now. The link is still not formatted according to ?userToken=XXX (btw, manually making a link like this works fine, i.e. :

 xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:61103/api/Test?userToken=XXX", true);

Comment: So using that url you get 200?

Comment: Thanks. This works, but it doesn't pass the content. It still stays within the Request object. Not particularly better than just basically omitting the string overload completely. I guess, there should be a way to form the Request on JScript in a better way.